# Elasticsearch: How to ignore/disable special characters in a search query?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I'm using Elasticsearch with fairly default settings, I think pretty much the only thing I changed was setting 'analyzer' => 'english'

If a user enters a [ character (or some of the other Elasticsearch special chars) into the text in their search query, ES throws an exception (I'm using elasticsearch-php). Is there a simple way (without writing my own pre-ES filtering) to simply have ES ignore known special characters? My users are never going to use them.

I thought it was kind of strange that this is default behaviour (to give an error), considering 99% of end users would never know about about using special chars.

I tried the "lenient" option, but that didn't help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html), search for the word reverse, you need to put \ before (